# pymongo - which approach is more efficient - find all vs find one?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

We are using mongodb, and accessing via pymongo. What approach is better to access a domain table that has about 1000 rows. note: findCat will be called 10,000 times in a loop?

**Cache to dictionary**

```
def __init__(self):
   self.categories_dict=Utils.todict(db.collection.find_all)

def findCat(self, key):
   return self.categories_dict(key)
```

or 
**Direct Query**

```
def findCat(key):
   #return object for the key
   return db.collection.find_one
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache should be faster because:

- No socket I/O
- No data conversion

But it's pretty easy to do a benchmark. And mongodb is really fast. Don't worry about it unless it's extremely performance intensive. 10,000 calls should be no problem for mongodb.